# How to identify an English sentence having other languages like Spanish using ColdFusion?

Tags: regex, validation, coldfusion, translation, cfml

Here I'm having a scenario, I've got a sentence with both English and Thai words like `'Hello World สวัสดีชาวโลก'`. Now I want to get the English word by using regex like `/[a-zA-Z ]*/`. But when I have the English words with Spanish like `'Hello World Hola Mundo'`. How can I identify the sentence having other languages like Spanish?

Do we have any option using regex / ColdFusion? Kindly share any suggestion and idea regarding this.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know how to solve it in coldfusion, but there are `polyglot` library written in python that can help you https://polyglot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Detection.html

Comment: Or `langdetect`, but it is not good for Chinese detection. You do not need the whole polyglot, just [`pycld2` library](https://pypi.org/project/pycld2/) - in Python.

Comment: Will it always be an English sentence with some other language that you're trying to filter for? Are you looking to translate or just identify a sentence without English words? And how accurate do you need it to be?

Comment: @Shawn I need to identify a sentence without English words. I mean If the sentence having other languages means I want to validate that.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to use an external API for this. Google has a language detection endpoint in their translate API.

https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/basic/detecting-language

Like mentioned about, regex will not give you accurate results.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't had much luck with a ColdFusion-only solution because many languages (like Spanish) use Latin characters. I've used the logic from this [Java script](https://www.javatips.net/api/fop-master/fop-trunk/fop-core/src/main/java/org/apache/fop/complexscripts/util/CharScript.java) with character ranges to detect Arabic, Bengali, Burmese / Myanmar, Cyrillic, Devangari, Ethiopic / Amharic, Georgian, Greek, Gujarati, Gurmukhi, Hangul, Hebrew, Kannada, Khmer, Malayalam, Mongolian, Oriya, Sinhala, Tamil, Telugu, Thai & Tibetan.

@Wiktor mentioned the [Polyglot library](https://github.com/aboSamoor/polyglot) and it claims to detect 165 languages using multiple techniques, but it is written in Python. The [OpenNLP](http://opennlp.apache.org/) Apache project supports language detection and here's some [sample java](https://github.com/Ruthwik/Language-Detection) to perform the detection. [Lingua](https://github.com/pemistahl/lingua) is a dedicated Java library for language detection and claims to be fast while working with short text phrases.  (Also, here's a list of other [NLP Java libraries](https://www.linuxlinks.com/excellent-java-natural-language-processing-tools/).)

In the case of emojis, they are very different and can cause parser problems; especially when passing off data to third-party processes. To detect & sanitize emojis, I recommend using the [emoji-java](https://github.com/vdurmont/emoji-java) java library. (I wrote a [ColdFusion CFC](https://github.com/JamoCA/cf-emoji-java) as a wrapper to the Java library.)

While researching this further, I found a ColdFusion-compatible Java library that works well and detects 68 languages. It's kju2-forked [language-detector](https://github.com/kju2/language-detector).  I've written a [cf-language-detector CFC](https://github.com/JamoCA/cf-language-detector).

```
languageDetector = new languageDetector();
languageDetector("Quel est votre nom?")          // CATALAN (French?)
languageDetector("Wie heißen Sie?")              // GERMAN
languageDetector("¿Cuál es tu nombre?")          // SPANISH
languageDetector("Πως σε λένε?")                 // GREEK
languageDetector("Как Вас зовут?")               // BELARUSIAN (Russian)
languageDetector("คุณชื่ออะไร?")                    // THAI
```

Comment: Lingua looks interesting.

Comment: "Hello World สวัสดีชาวโลก" = THAI, but "Hello World Hola Mundo" = ENGLISH and "Hola Mundo" = GALICIAN since the the test string is rather short.  Pl,ease note that this library will only return a single, primary language.

Comment: Ahh...... Returning just one language might limit the usefulness.  Was it OpenNLP that reported a confidence score for all detected languages?

Comment: And I'll throw some Kudos your way. One of the things that makes you a hero is that you spent a few hours building a CFC to solve a problem you saw on StackOverflow. :-)

Comment: @Shawn I'm evaluating Lingua too. It works, but has serious performance and/or thread issues. Lingua also returns single language, but is 131mb compared to 1.2mb. A Latin 36 word phrase takes 2ms, but hangs when using Lingua.

Comment: The Apache OpenNLP project contains 37 different JAR files. The process for detecting languages appears to involve a lot more steps (including "training").

Answer (score 1):

I don't think regex is the right tool to face this problem. Think about, for instance, the English verb *to dare* which, without the *to*, is the same as the Italian infinitive *dare*, which is *to give*. How would you distinguish these two *dare*-s from each other? By context? How much context? This is not a regex' job.

A good example of the complexity of the task is just the previous paragraph. Your intention is to have a tool which can parse that paragraph and distinguish the three occurrences of dare in that comment. But what language should be assigned to the third *dare*? Actually no language, because that occurrence is referring to the graphical representation of *dare* (the sequence of the four symbols *d*, *a*, *r*, *e*), not to any language.